# JQuery live with Dragable not working dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i have this code to only call the multiselect function to the current dragged element.

but the problem is that when i drag and drop it to the other box it will be created by dynamicly generated html so i have to use live or on jquery function but i tried and it not works anybody have any idea to do this?

```
    $( ".ui-state-highlight" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        stop : function(){
            $(this).find(".multiselect").multiselect();
        }
    });
```

This is the code and i want that when i drop an element to the dropable box then there is a jquery multiselect which will start working.

any body have any other solution ? or this one too  that how can i call live in dragables stop event?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not because of draggable 
check your jquery version in 1.9+ version live will nor support instead of live you can use other way
follw this link

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

Comment: no my version is **1.6+**, and live is working fine on other elements